# Linking to a local copy of Bootstrap breaks CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So here is the problem. I'm developing an angular+bootstrap app for work, and I'm at the very beginning stages of development. I'm trying to build just some of the UI using bootstrap. However, for some reason, any time I link to a local copy of Bootstrap, all the css breaks. It doesn't matter if it is minified or not.

Here is what I have right now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/app/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
</head>
<nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation"><a>Option A</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a>Option B</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a>Option C</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a>Option D</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Stuff goes here!</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the cdn version of Bootstrap and un-comment my local copy, everything works fine. I'd prefer to use a local copy so I can work offline. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Just to show that I have the local path correct, here is the project folder structure (ignoring the node_modules folder contents)

```
Client
\---app
    +---core
    \---lib
         +---angular  (ignoring content of this folder)
         +---bootstrap
                bootstrap.css
         \---font-awesome-4.5.0 (ignoring content of this folder)
\---node_modules (ignoring content of this folder)
Server
   web-server.js
```

**EDIT 2**

I was checking out the developer tools in Chrome to see what errors there could be (thanks to Anonymouse for giving me the idea) and here is what popped up

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <              bootstrap.js:1
```

following that will take me to index.html and highlight the line where I have the script tag for bootstrap.js.

here is the next error

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost:7000/lib/bootstrap/boostrap.css"
```

Comment: have you tryied copying the cdn version into your bootstrap.css

Comment: What do you mean by "If I...commit my local copy, everything works fine."?

Comment: Try to confirm you are using the correct path to the local CSS file.

Comment: @frederickf I can confirm that the path to the local CSS file is correct.

Comment: @AguV I just tried doing that, it didn't work

Comment: What version is your local copy?  And define 'break'?

Comment: @TaylorAckley My local copy is the most updated verstion of Bootstrap, which I believe is 3.3.6. By break, I mean none of the bootstrap classes I have added to my html work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Good News**

I figured out the problem. The problem originated in my server code.

Here is the code for reference

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../');

app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/app'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) { res.sendFile( rootPath + 'client/app/core/index.html'); });

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port 8000...');
```

The problem was in the line

```
app.use(express.static(rootPath + '/app');
```

it should have been

```
app.use(express.static(rootPath + 'client/app');
```

I didn't make sure to have the path correct for when express scans for css and js files.

---

Moral of the story, never gloss over the small details.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a CDN, instead get the local version from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/). This is due to simplicity, speed, and flexibility. All you have to do (which I do), is create a script in root to upgrade all my local libs using the cdn (see below)

```
mkdir updateLib
cd updateLib
mkdir css
mkdir js
mkdir img
cd css

REM use Curl -O http://cdn.url here (you ust have cygwin installed)

cd ..
cd js

REM use Curl -O http://cdn.url here (you ust have cygwin installed)

cd ..
cd ..
copy lib/img/* updateLib/img

rm -rfv lib
REN updateLib lib

msg %username% "libs updated!"
```

If your issue is using the CDN, this is a solution to that as well.

Comment: My local version is from the bootstrap site. Also, I will give this a try.

Comment: @MuffinTheKid remove the CDN link then, and uncomment your local. You also need the JS, and I suggest the CSS map as well (for debugging purposes).

Comment: did all that, and it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @MuffinTheKid Is there an error in the developer console?

Comment: there are two errors, I updated the post with the errors

Comment: @MuffinTheKid I've got your comment, but I can't see it yet. It takes a while sometimes, but if you could check it went through, that'd be good :-)